# PowerPivot DAX Max of two values

Tags: max, dax, powerpivot

I have two columns and I need to extract the maximum value of those two for every row in my table. I have looked at the Max, Maxx and Maxa, but they all have input for just one column.

How would I write following expression in a Calculated column:

```
=max(
    Table1[Column1],
    Table1[Column2]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of MAX, you can just use a simple IF to achieve what you want:

```
= IF(Table1[Column1] >= Table1[Column2], Table1[Column1], Table1[Column2])
```

Comment: Ah yes, of course! Thanks. 
It creates some long ugly formulas, but it works :)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you should write the formula exactly as you described:

```
=max(
Table1[Column1],
Table1[Column2]
)
```

MAX function in dax exists in 2 versions: one takes a single column, the other takes 2 singular expressions.

Comment: That's what I tried. It just yields errors. And the max() function as described in DAX only takes 1 expression

Comment: See the second description: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/max-function-dax

Comment: @Martin - I use MAX with 2 arguments all the time without any problems. If you get any errors, give me a specific example and we will figure out why.

Comment: ah it's because my workcomputer uses Excel 2013. Excel 2016 works with two expressions.